# Beginner Questions (Formatting, "Filepath was unexpected at this time")

Tags: file, batch-file

I am new to batch files and I only need a very simple thing done.
I would like a batch file to take a text file which is a list of filepaths --

Filelist.txt

Begin File>>

O:\X\Y\Z\Board BOM Rev 4.xls         >>Files

O:\X\Y\U                             >>Entire filepaths

< End File

and then copy the files (not the names of the files, to clarify) to a given location.
Say that the batch file is in O:\X\Y\Z (And so is the text file), and I would like to copy all of those files to that folder. I have tried to use this code

> @echo off
>
> set input="O:\X\Y\Z\Filelist.txt"
>
> set dest=%cd%
>
> for /f %%i in "input" do xcopy "%%i" %dest%\ /S

To do what I need to do, but I get the aforementioned error. I have done very little with batch files, so corrections with explanations would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, to use your variable "input" write `%input%`

Second, for the correct format of `for` you have to put parantheses around it:

```
  for /f %%i in ("%input%") do xcopy "%%i" %dest%\ /S
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1st. (input)

In the first `set` you have double-quoted wrong the value, that formatting is for extraordinary cases, not this time.

> 2nd. (dest)

You need to ensure to double-quote every `"variable=value"` (at least when they are string variables and when can contains spaces)

but anyways you can simplify the code a little to don't depend on that `dest` variable,

> 3rd. (For)

The `dest` variable inside `for` has the same quote problem, also you are typing incorrectly the `input` variable, and `for` syntax can be improved to prevent future errors by agroupping the commands using the agroupation operators `()`.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off

set "input=O:\X\Y\Z\Filelist.txt"

REM set "dest=%cd%"

for /f "Usebackq Delims=" %%i in ("%input%") do (
    xcopy "%%i" ".\" /S
)
```

PS: Forgive my English.